# From string to numb calc result

Tags: javascript

I am familiar with js at a very, very low level. I decided to start with a pet project - a calculator.
The following problem arose, when I try to display the result of operations in p-tag, NaN is displayed.
Please tell me the best way to implement.

```js
var value = [];
input = (btn) => {
  document.getElementById('value').value = "";
  value.push(btn.value);
  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('value').value += value[i];
  }
}
calc = () => {
  var result;
  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    result += parseInt(value[i]);
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = result;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="value" id="value">
      <p id="result"></p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" name="(" value="(" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name=")" value=")" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="/" value="/" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="*" value="*" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <br>
      <input type="button" name="7" value="7" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="8" value="8" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="9" value="9" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="^" value="^" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <br>
      <input type="button" name="4" value="4" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="5" value="5" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="6" value="6" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="-" value="-" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <br>
      <input type="button" name="1" value="1" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="2" value="2" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="3" value="3" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="+" value="+" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <br>
      <input type="button" name="0" value="0" class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="." value="." class="but" onclick="input(this);">
      <input type="button" name="=" value="=" onclick="calc();">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[calc error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMHBw.png)

Comment: `undefined` + `number` results in `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

I checked and saw that you end up converting the characters inside the input to numbers

But when you put one of the math symbols like +, it does not become a number and the calculation is not done.

Change your code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var value1 = "";
    var value2 = "";
    var operator = "";
    var fullValue = "";
    input = (btn) => {

        fullValue += btn.value;
        //  operator is null and value is number = number 1
        if (!isNaN(btn.value) && operator == "") {
            value1 += btn.value;
        }
        // operator is not null and value is number=number2
        else if (!isNaN(btn.value) && operator != "") {
            value2 += btn.value;
        }
        // value is not number = operator
        else {
            operator = btn.value;
        }
        document.getElementById('value').value = fullValue;

    }
    calc = () => {
        var result = 0;
        // check operator type and implement action
        switch (operator) {
            case "+":
                result = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2);
                break;
            case "-":
                result = parseInt(value1) - parseInt(value2);
                break;
            case "*":
                result = parseInt(value1) * parseInt(value2);
                break;
            case "/":
                result = parseInt(value1) / parseInt(value2);
                break;
        }
        document.getElementById('result').innerText = result;
    }
</script>
```